# Blur event not fired on some devices (VueJS, iOS / Android)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, vue.js, onblur

Actually i need help to fix a strange bug that occurs on mobile devices that are < iOS13 for iPhone / iPad and on Android tablets (works on mobile, probably linked to android version)

It appears that when we enter in an input field and exit it by tapping on another field or tapping on container to loose focus, the blur event is correctly sent on some of my input but on others its not.

Here is the code :
[validationModal.vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx9Qk.png)

```
    <label class="validation-cap">E-mail interlocuteur</label>
    <div class="error-message" v-if="mailPersoControls.showPictoControl && mailPersoControls.statut !== 'ADRESSE_VALIDE' && mailPersoControls.message">{{ mailPersoControls.message }}</div>
    <div class="input-relative-validation">
        <input type="text" id="PM_email_perso" class="inputWithPicto" :class="isProspect ? 'border-prospect' : 'border-client'" name="PM_email_perso" v-on:blur="validateEmail('perso')" v-model="mailPerso" />
        <div class="validation-container" v-if="mailPersoControls.showPictoControl">
            <div v-if="mailPersoControls.isLoading" class="loader-control"></div>
            <span v-else class="span-validation-icon">
                <img @click="validateEmail('perso')" :src="mailPersoControls.statut !== 'ADRESSE_VALIDE' ? (mailPersoControls.statut === 'NC' ? require(`Images/shared/control-nc.png`) : require(`Images/shared/control-ko.png`)) : require(`Images/shared/control-ok.png`)" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label class="validation-cap">Téléphone professionnel</label>
    <div class="input-relative-validation">
        <input type="text" id="PM_tel_pro" class="inputWithPicto" :class="isProspect ? 'border-prospect' : 'border-client'" name="PM_tel_pro" v-on:blur="validatePhone('PRO')"  :disabled="isClientBanque" v-model="telephonePro" />
        <div class="validation-container" v-if="telephoneProControls.showPictoControl">
            <div v-if="telephoneProControls.isLoading" class="loader-control"></div>
            <span v-else class="span-validation-icon">
                <img @click="validatePhone('PRO')" :src="telephoneProControls.statut !== 'VALIDE' ? (telephoneProControls.statut === 'NC' ? require(`Images/shared/control-nc.png`) : require(`Images/shared/control-ko.png`)) : require(`Images/shared/control-ok.png`)" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The logic behind the code is to have inputs that validate email and phone with an API http call and display a green check or red cross (and loader to wait) in the input.

On the screenshot the input who validate email works fine and triggers blur event correctly (showing validate or error picto and loader in the input linked), but the phone number input doesnt react to blur event (http request is sent onBlur on the email field but never in the phone field)
All inputs works on Desktop, on iOS devices >= 13, on Android >= X (did not found the target version when the bug occurs)

Stack : VueJS2, axios

Comment: `Here is the code` - no, that's a picture of code, which took you longer to create than it would've to simply paste the code in the question, as is required

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem was in the validatePhone method, where i replace '+' by '00' with regex and replaceAll. On some device (browser version), s.replaceAll(xxxx) is not a function